# HiveQL - Using range filtering in exists checks results in error regarding correlated subquery

Tags: sql, hive

So I want to achieve something like "Check if there's any entry between two timestamp" and all I can come up is some code like this:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE sometable.timestamp between othertable.time1 and othertable.time2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

And then Hive is screaming this to me:

```
We can't transform correlated subquery having where correlated condition other than AND or in a non-equal expression.
```

Judging from the literal meaning of the error message, I'm thinking that when using columns from other tables (thus forming a correlated subquery), maybe you can't put any WHERE conditions with `<` `>` or `BETWEEN...AND...` with a SELECT clause inside an `EXISTS()`.

So how can I do to achieve the thing I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can write subquery in select like oracle.
You can left join the subquery to the main table and get output. So, it may look like this

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN sometable.timestamo is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM othertable 
left join sometable ON sometable.timestamp between othertable.time1 and othertable.time2
```